# How to keep Account Team when Account Owner is updated(mass update) via Data Loader?

Tags: data, loader

How to keep Account Team when Account Owner is updated(mass update) via Data Loader?

I am trying to do mass update on Account owner via data loader, but want to keep account team members as is. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Still not possible, as of Data Loader v56 (Winter '23).